# Rails: Fetch nth table record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I know I can find the first user in my database in the command line with,

```
User.first
```

And I can find the last with

```
User.last
```

my question is how would I call the 11th user in a database.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can do

```
User.all[10]
```

User.all gives you an array or objects with index starting from 0. To access 11th user you can do that.

Comment: While this is syntactically pleasing, it's really the most expensive way to get what you need. This will load all users into memory so you can access the 10th one in the resulting array.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`offset`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/offset) with `order`:

```
User.offset(10).order(:id).first
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
User.limit(1).offset(10)
```

That reduces the work to a SQL statement that looks like this:

```
SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  LIMIT 1 OFFSET 10
```

Using `all` will require loading all the users into memory and then finding the 11th one in that array. Quite pricey.